# ModelMultipleChoiceField' object has no attribute 'to_field_name'

Tags: django, django-forms

These are my files:

models.py:

```
class Pierwszy(models.model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=15,blank =True, null= True)
   extra = models.CharField(max_length=15,blank =True, null= True)
   kids = models.ManyToManyField('Pierwszy', related_name="pierwszy_children", null=True, blank=True)

class Drugi(Pierwszy):
   ext_name = models.CharField(max_length=15,blank =True, null= True)
```

views.py:

```
class DrugiForm(ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(DrugiForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
    if instance and instance.pk:
      if instance.name is not None:
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

   class Meta:
     model = Drugi
     fields = ('ext_name','name','kids','extra')
     widgets = {
      'kids' : forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=None, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()),
     }
     hidden = {
       'extra'
     }
```

template:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
{{ hidden }}
{% endfor %}
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
  <div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
  <p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
</form>
```

On this stage I just want to see the current state of object. I don't want to edit fields.

I use `queryset=None` for kids' widget, because I don't want to show all possibilities, just show list of names (name field) connected to instance.

i'm not sure where should I add filter to queryset (in widget def or in **init**), but the biggest problem is that, whatever I do, I get

```
ModelMultipleChoiceField' object has no attribute 'to_field_name'
```

And I'm stacked now. On Google there's only one case, but this is about overriding the widget/Field - which is not my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `widgets` dictionary expects the values to be `widget` instances such as `TextArea()`, `TextInput()`, etc.

If you want to use `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField`, you could do something like this

```
class DrugiForm(ModelForm):
    kids = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Pierwszy.objects.none(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DrugiForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.pk:
        if instance.name is not None:
            self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

    class Meta:
        model = Drugi
        fields = ('ext_name','name','kids','extra')
```

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'all' -

Comment: Updated the answer. You need to use `Pierwszy.objects.none()` to get an empty queryset.

Comment: Got a orphan record in database - this  makes stupid errors. Thank you very much @RodXavier